# Check for URL is working or not using

Tags: c#

```
string url = "www.google.com";

public bool UrlIsValid(string url)
{
    bool br = false;
    try
    {
                    IPHostEntry ipHost =  Dns.GetHostEntry(url);
                                     br = true;
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        br = false;
    }
    return br;
}
```

Above program will output true but when I change string to

```
string url = "https://www.google.com";
```

I got output as `false`.

How can I get output for my second case?

Comment: Do you want to assure that the hostname of the url is known?

Comment: The protocol on which a host serves responses isn't really relevant to Dns.GetHostEntry.

Comment: What purpose is `UrlIsValid` meant to *serve*? What decisions does the consuming code make based on the results?

Comment: Check if there is a proxy blocking the request.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the Uri class to parse the url string.

```
public bool UrlIsValid(string url) {
   return UrlIsValid(new Uri(url));
}


public bool UrlIsValid(Uri url)
{
    bool br = false;
    try
    {
         IPHostEntry ipHost =  Dns.GetHostEntry(url.DnsSafeHost);
         br = true;
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        br = false;
    }
    return br;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dns.GetHostEntry is looking for a domain name, not a url. Try converting the string to a URI and using URI.DnsSafeHost first

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
string domain = uri.DnsSafeHost;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274677/checking-if-url-is-up-and-working-if-it-is-to-redirect-to-that-url-itself-else)

```
Uri siteUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(siteUri);

// now, request the URL from the server, to check it is valid and works
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse ())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
    }
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: This would not work if the page required login. In this case you would receive a 401; but I guess it is a matter of the definition of "working". :)